# sonarQube null check

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, sonarqube

I have a code similar to

```
boolean shouldPublish(existingValues, updatedValues){
  if(existingValues==null) 
     return false;
  // compare values
  if(!(Double.compare(existingValues.conFactor,updatedValues.conFactor) !=0) || !(existingValue.url.equals(updatedValues.url))){
    return true;
  }
}
```

SonarQube is giving me a bug saying a NullpointerException could be thrown on existingValues at Double.compare statement. Could anyone help me to resolve this please.

Comment: This is not legal java syntax; the types for the parameters are missing. --- Two remarks: In java, it is common to have spaces before and after binary operators. Likewise, keywords are normally separated by spaces (`if(existingValues==null) ` -> `if (existingValues == null) `. - Even if possible, it is recommended to not skip the brackets of one-line code-blocks (`if(existingValues==null)  return false;` -> `if (existingValues == null) { return false; }`).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you provided not valid Java code, because you omitted the parameter types.

When can a NullPointerException be thrown? Every time you try to dereference a variable which points to null.

An NPE cannot be thrown because of the nullability of `existingValues`, because the previous null-check takes care of it.

But `updatedValues.conFactor`, `updatedValues.url` and especially **the equality check** on `existingValue.url` could throw an NPE.

Don't just add those references above, think about whether you can enforce non-nullability upon the objects when creating them in the first place by using [Design-by-contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) .

Comment: I want to note that the `Double.compare(existingValues.conFactor,updatedValues.conFactor)` could also throw a NPE because of unboxing _if_ these are `Double`s and not `double`s.